# Unable to send array value to java controller using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my code

```
   //javaScript code 

    var sampleDataList= [];

    var dataSample = {
            name:"name",
            id:"id"
    };
    sampleDataList.push(dataSample);
    sampleDataList.push(dataSample);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "saveData",
        data : sampleDataList,
        //data:mydata,
        contentType : "json",
        async:false,
        success : function(data) {
        },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });

    //TO class

    public class DataSample {
        private String name;
        private String id;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    //Controller

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void saveDatas(ArrayList<DataSample> dataSamp){
            System.out.println(asdf);
        }
```

am able to hit the conttroller but dataSamp(parameter of saveDatas method) doesnot have any value. It is received as empty list.

Please suggest what went wrong in my code ? or please me how get this done ?

Comment: Solved the issue.Had two issues in my ajax call.After adding below two parameters in my ajax it worked,

1) data : JSON.stringify(sampleDataList),  (@ema's suggesion)
2) contentType : "application/json"

Comment: So why have you marked my answer as 'is not useful'?

Comment: @ema i dint mark it.

Comment: @ema ya that's what am also saying i dint mark it. When i first saw ur answer it was already down voted.

Comment: ok, sorry for embarrasing, never mind, you can just upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify() when sending ajax-request:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "saveData",
        data : JSON.stringify(sampleDataList),
        //data:mydata,
        ...
```

And if I'm not mistaken also you need @RequestBody annotation in request parameter :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void saveDatas(@RequestBody ArrayList<DataSample> dataSamp){
            System.out.println(asdf);
        }
```

Add  jackson dependency for converting json to object and vice versa

```
<dependency><!-- jackson -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version></version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: where do i need to add the jackson dependency conversion , in web.xml?

Comment: add to the pom.xml file if you are using maven.